# Extract information from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a boolean matrix like this:

```
      1     2     3     4     5
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I need to get the row number and the column number of the TRUE values. However, the values which row number equals column number should be discard, e.g. `(1,1) (2,2)...`. Also, since in the matrix `(m,n) = (n,m)`, I only need one value of the pair, e.g. only `(4,5)` is needed, not `(5,4)`.

For example, can I get the value into a matrix like this:

```
    [,1]  [,2]
[1,]   1     3
[2,]   4     5
```

I've tried `which()` but don't know how to filter the results. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do:

```
df = data.frame(row=rep(1:(nrow(m)-1),(nrow(m)-1):1),
                col=unlist(sapply(2:ncol(m), function(i) i:ncol(m))))

df[m[upper.tri(m)],]
#   row col
#2    1   3
#10   4   5
```

Comment: I think this is a creative approach (+1) but might benefit from a bit of explanation, since it's less intuitive.  Basically it creates a `data.frame` of row and column indices for the upper triangle of a matrix with the same dimensions as `m`.  Then return the rows of the data frame (which correspond to row-column combinations of the matrix) that correspond to TRUE values in the upper triangle of `m`.

Comment: yes it's a little bit alternative, I agree :) exactly, the idea is to generate the `row` index and `col` index of the vector `m[upper.tri(m)]` in a `data.frame`, and then filter this `data.frame` where the values are `TRUE`

Comment: also worth noting that this solution returns a `data.frame`, so wrap it in `as.matrix()` if the OP is planning on treating it as such

Answer (score 2):

Here is your [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
m <- as.matrix(
      read.table(text = "      1     2     3     4     5
                         1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
                         2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
                         3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
                         4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
                         5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE")
     )

m[lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)] <- FALSE # you want to ignore row index >= col index

which(m, arr.ind=TRUE) # returns the TRUEs from the upper triangle
```

Returns:

```
  row col
1   1   3
4   4   5
```